# How to make a div takes 100% width when other div is hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea is that one div takes 100% of the screen <***map***> when the second one is hidden <***chart***>. Also I would like to know why when I click on the input tag it intimately executes the function  and doesn't wait for the button to be clicked.

```js
function hidechart() {
  var x = document.getElementById("chart");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body, #fullheight {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
.leaflet-container { 
  position: fixed;
  width:  50%;
  height: 100%;
}
#chart{
  position:absolute;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50px;
  top:2%;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map" ></div>
<div class="btn-group" style="position:fixed">
  <button onclick="hidechart()" >Graficas</button>
  <button type="button" id="alldep" class="btn" >Todos</button> 
</div>

<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:14%; width:10%;" type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="userInput" />
  <button style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:5%; width:8%;",stype="button" onclick="query();">Consultar</button>
</form>

<div id="chart"  align="right">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="chart-area"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So essentially you want each of them to occupy the same space, and each will show depending on which one is hidden?

Comment: Yes, I want then to occupy the same space when both are displayed, and I only want to hide the chart dive, so the map div can take all the width.

Comment: In that case, It would make sense to just layer them on top of each other, and just hide the top layer on class change.

Comment: Sorry, I just edit my last comment,I did not make myself clear(I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: It's ok. I'm sure we'll figure out what your intent is, and go through it. I just want to be clear: The layers are <chart> goes on top of <map>, and <map> only shows when <chart> is hidden. but how does a person 'hide' chart?

Comment: There is a button "Graficas" that calls the hidechart function and that function hides the dive chart

Answer (score 0):

Is this the button functionality you're looking for?

```js
var map = document.getElementById("map");
var chart = document.getElementById("chart");

function hideChart() {
  chart.classList.add("hide");
}

function query() {
  alert("query");
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    html, body, #fullheight {
        min-height: 100% !important;
        height: 100%;
    }
.leaflet-container { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    
#map {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#chart{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    
#chart.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="map" ></div>
   <div class="btn-group" style="position:fixed">
      <button onclick="hideChart()" >Graficas</button>
      <button type="button" id="alldep" class="btn" >Todos</button> 
  </div>

  <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="userInput" />
      <button type="button" onclick="query();">Consultar</button>
  </form>

  <div id="chart" align="right">
      <div class="row">
          <div id="chart-area">
            <h1>This is where the chart is</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is really close, but the div that is up is not resizing when the other one is hide, instead the div from the bottom is putting in front of the other overlaping the content

Comment: That was my original question. If they're on top of each other it's fine, but I just don't know what the scenario is. What is in chart? What is in map? I don't understand the logic of what is happening. Can you walk me through what a user would do to experience this?

Comment: Ok, my bad, in the map div there is an leaflet map, the idea is that this div takes 100% of the screen, but there is another div with data graphs that can be hide or not, but when is not hide the idea is that both divs take 50% of the screen not one on the top of the other.

Comment: So what you mean to say is they *don't* take up some same space, rather they're half and half until the chart hides, where the map assumes the rest of the width?

Comment: Yes! that's what i mean

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Ok. I'll adapt for jquery. It's way easier